# MySql constraint violation. Inserting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have database with 5 tables

```
students    PK    : ID -> anum, first, last
studentinfo PK/FK : ID -> why, student_commenets, finished, aidyear
Times       PK/FK : ID -> signintime, counselor_start_time, 
                           additional_time, finish_time
counselor   PK/FK : ID -> firstcounselor, secondcounselor, thirdcounselor
Comments    PK/FK : ID -> counselorcomments, additional_commenets
```

I have a page called signinpage.php

on that page I have to write to three different tables (student, studentinfo, and time)

My code is as fallows :

```
if (empty($errors) === true) 
{
include('core/queries/inserts.updates.selects/students.php');   
include('core/queries/inserts.updates.selects/studentinfo.php');
include('core/queries/inserts.updates.selects/signintime.php'); 

$dbh = null;    
header('location: signedin.php');
exit(); 
}
```

each of the files are actual insert queries. (if you yall need to see them I will update this post)

The error I am having is :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`times`,
>   CONSTRAINT `times_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `students`
>   (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

To add on to this, the first query (the students.php and the second query studentinfo.php)
are inserting just fine. Same ID, the problem occurs with the signintime inserting into table : times.

In phpmyadmin both tables (studentinfo and times) are configured alike with both have cascade on delete and update to the original table (student) since the student him/her starts the session (which is the PK ID).

How can I solved this error?

Edit :

```
<?php
require('core/init.php');

try 
{
    $null = NULL;
    $query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `times` (signintime) VALUES (:signintime)");
    $query->bindParam(':signintime' , $null);
    $query->execute();
}

        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
                error_log($e->getMessage());
                die($e->getMessage());
        }   
?>
```

Comment: Hi, this isn't related to your question, but you may benefit from reading this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878

Comment: thank you for that. with the needs of this business they must store redundant data (anum = student id) because multiple students come in multiple times. other then that I feel this is in a good form. However tyvm for the reading material!

Answer (score 0):

Your table design looks wrong to me. I'm assuming there can be multiple entries in the `times` table for each row in the `students` table. In that case, you would need the following columns in `times`:

```
id - PK
student_id - FK
signintime
counselor_start_time
additional_time
finish_time
```

Then each row for a particular student would have the same `student_id` value, but different `id` values.

Comment: there already is a student id which the anum (sorry i didnt mention that) and with that I expect multiple students to come back to the office multiple times. So using anum as a primary key / FK would cause violations? no?

Comment: I'm saying it should only be used as the foreign key in the `times` table, which needs its own primary key separate to this.

Comment: Also one thing that needs to be included is that there is no database that holds student info. The student them selves inserts the record to the student table. That is my problem. I am inserting to the student table, student info table, and times table all at once.

Answer (score 0):

The following statements and example is different from the tables you have mentioned but the **thought is still the same**.

The reason why the error was generated is because you are trying to insert a value on a *child* table in which that value is not yet present on the *parent* table. The *child* table means that it is dependent on the other table (*which is the Parent*).

To explain further, consider the following schema,

```
CREATE TABLE StudentList
(
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  NAme VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE AddressList
(
  StudentID INT,
  Address VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT tb_fk FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) 
    REFERENCES StudentList(ID)
);

INSERT INTO StudentList VALUES (1, 'Jon');
INSERT INTO StudentList VALUES (2, 'Skeet');

INSERT INTO AddressList VALUES (1, 'Hello');
INSERT INTO AddressList VALUES (2, 'World');
INSERT INTO AddressList VALUES (1, 'Other Address');
```

There are two tables: `StudentList` and `AddressList`. The table `Address` is the child table and which is dependent to  table `StudentList` (*also called the Parent table*). The only values that are allowed to be inserted on column `StudentID` of table `AddressList` is only `1 and 2` because those are the only `ID`s found on table `StudentList`.

When you try to insert record with ID other than `1 and 2` on table `Address`, eg

```
INSERT INTO AddressList VALUES (1, 'Other Address');
```

it will generate an error telling that:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`db_2_ec2e8`.`addresslist`, CONSTRAINT `tb_fk` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`StudentID`) REFERENCES `studentlist` (`ID`)):

because the value of the column `StudentID` being inserted on the table is not available on the parent table (*StudentList*).

So, I hoped that this will help you understand now.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a941af/1)

Comment: I am inserting into student, studentinfo, and times at the same time with the same php script. at the moment the sessionid or PK : ID is the FK of all my tables except the student table.

Comment: Also one thing that needs to be included is that there is no database that holds student info. The student them selves inserts the record to the student table. That is my problem. I am inserting to the student table, student info table, and times table all at once.